# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: php

Ola pessoal estou desenvolvendo um site imobiliario e na area que lista os imóveis, não esta aparecendo as fotos dos imóveis. e esta gerando o seguinte erro

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) thumb.php**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

código onde mostra o caminho da imagem

```
<?php

/**
 * descricao Imagem
  *
 * @author janaina
   */
class Fotos {
/*
 * metodo para exibir a foto
 * com varios tamanhos
 */

public static function Exibir($imagem, $w, $h,$f=null) {

    if ($imagem == null):
        $imagem = 'sem-foto.jpg';
    endif;
    if ($f != null && $f == true) {
       $fotos = ".".Rotas::$siteUrl . Rotas::$pastaFotos . 'thumb.php?src=' . $imagem . '&w=' . $w . '&h=' . $h;
    } else {
       $fotos = Rotas::$siteUrl . Rotas::$pastaFotos . 'thumb.php?src=' . $imagem . '&w=' . $w . '&h=' . $h;
    }


    $img = '<img src="' . $fotos . '" >';
    return $img;


    // echo $fotos; 
}

/**
 * 
 * @param type $imagem
 * @param type $w
 * @param type $h
 * @return string  caminho da foto
 *  este Ã© o metodo somente quando a imagem for link
 */
public static function ImagemLink($imagem, $w, $h) {

    $fotos = Rotas::$siteUrl . Rotas::$pastaFotos . 'thumb.php?src=' . $imagem . '&w=' . $w . '&h=' . $h;

    return $fotos;


    // echo $fotos; 
}

/**
 * metodo que faz tratamento do upload
 */
public static function Upload() {

}

/**
 * metodo que dele a foto da pasta
 * @param type $arquivo (pega o nome da foto)
 * e apaga da pasta
 */
public static function Apagar($arquivo=null) {

    if(empty($arquivo)):
       $arquivo = '00000.jpg'; 
    endif;

    $foto = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . Rotas::$pastaFotos . $arquivo;

    // se a foto existe
    if (file_exists($foto)):

      unlink($foto); // apago ela da pasta

    else:

        echo '<br><center><strong>Erro: Imagem inexistente</strong></center>';

    endif;
}
```

}

Comment: E qual o conteúdo do arquivo `thumb.php`?

Comment: é uma biblioteca TimThumb.php que  redimensionar as imagens no tamanho exato que eu quero.

Comment: E você apenas renomeou o arquivo para `thumb.php`?

Comment: exato, porem eu baixei o arquivo novamente deixando o nome original, porém mesmo assim não funcionou